# Recurrent event Survival analysis in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I want to conduct a recurrent survival analysis of my data which is about a firm getting cyber breach. The data includes IT budget, general financial variables, event time, risk factor disclosure in 10k report. I am interested to investigate how the risk factor disclosure and IT budget influence the survival time of getting breached. So here is my code:

In here, `start` is t, `stop` is t+1, `status` is event, `gvkey` is the index, and `CTL_sic` is industry code.

```
survival1 <- coxph(
    Surv(start, stop, status) ~ numwords + PE_it_budget + CTL_maketcap + CTL_roe + CTL_liq + CTL_mb + cluster(gvkey) + strata(CTL_sic), 
    method = "breslow", 
    data = combinedata)
```

Am I right in this set-up?
Also, how can I specify an interaction term in the model between `numwords` and IT budget?

The data structure roughly likes this.

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORo3T.jpg)

Comment: Hi I cannot comment on the cluster and strata call without seeing the data or understanding the full context of the analysis. To specify interaction term, add numwords:PE_it_budget to your formula.

Comment: @Start I added the image. Can you see that?

Comment: Hi Zhaoxin, what I meant is, your question is a bit too broad. I do not know your data or what exactly you want to get out of the model, so it is hard to comment or answer you question. I suggest thinking about the exact question, and if it is more statistical in nature, you can post it on https://stats.stackexchange.com/